# Django auth error when using mongoengine

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, mongoengine

I am using mongoengine (v0.9) as a mapper for my Django (v1.8) project running by Python 3.4.

Although I have added following codes to settings.py file, I still keep receiving this error while a user try to connect to admin  using django default admin process)

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'mongoengine.django.mongo_auth',
    'myapp',
)

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('mongoengine.django.auth.MongoEngineBackend',)

SESSION_ENGINE = 'mongoengine.django.sessions'

connect('mymongodb')
```

> AttributeError at /admin/login/
>
> 'MetaDict' object has no attribute 'pk'
>
> Request Method:    POST
>
> Request URL:   http://myapp.dev:8000/admin/login/
>
> Django Version:    1.8
>
> Exception Type:    AttributeError
>
> Exception Value:   'MetaDict' object has no attribute 'pk'
>
> Exception Location:    c:\Programs\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth__init__.py in login, line 111
>
> Python Executable: c:\Programs\Python34\python.exe
>
> Python Version:    3.4.2

P.S: I have also tried customizing Login Process by writing URL patterns, template and views, but will get same error on calling "login()" function.

Comment: have you find any solution.I has the same error

Comment: @himanshudua Unfortunately not yet. I've wrote a temporary user manager class for now. As soon as finding any solution I will update my code and this question.

Comment: @himanshudua  got the solution ?

Answer (score 1):

I had a same issue that you guys were having. I created a new github project to resolve my issue. You can download it or modify it or extract code for your own use by going to https://github.com/robintiwari/django-me. Please let me know if you have any questions on how to use it. I also have an example project regarding configuration. To be specific, you should find an answer on this code https://github.com/robintiwari/django-me/blob/master/djangome/mongo_auth/middlewares.py

Answer (score 0):

Change in this file 
c:\Programs\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth__init__.py

```
try:
   request.session[SESSION_KEY] = user._meta.pk.value_to_string(user)
except Exception:
   request.session[SESSION_KEY] = user.id
```